# Is there any way to restrict chrome browser updation while we are running javascript application

Tags: javascript, browser, operating-system, google-chrome-os, chromebook

We are using a javascript application in chrome box which is running as a kiosk application. Chrome OS is updating automatically.

Can we able to restrict the auto update of Chrome OS from javascript level and from the OS level?

Thanks in advance.